# If $K=\mathbb{C}(x)(\sqrt{-1-x^2})$, then $K=\mathbb{C}(t)$ where $t=(i-x)^{-1}\sqrt{(-1-x^2)}/(i-x)$?

Tags: field-theory, transcendence-degree

This is exercise 7 of Section 19 on Transcendence Degrees in Morandi's Field and Galois Theory.

Let $K=\mathbb{C}(x)(\sqrt{-1-x^2})$. Show that $[K:\mathbb{C}(x)]=2$, and show that $K=\mathbb{C}(t)$ if $t=(i-x)^{-1}\sqrt{(-1-x^2)}/(i-x)$.

It was easy for me to show $[K:\mathbb{C}(x)]=2$, but I can't reach the conclusion $K=\mathbb{C}(t)$. The formula for $t$ above is exactly as it is typeset in the book, but I wonder if it really means
$$
t=(i-x)^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{-1-x^2}{i-x}},\qquad (*)
$$
otherwise why wouldn't it be written as $t=\sqrt{(-1-x^2)}/(i-x)^2$ or even $t=(i-x)^{-2}\sqrt{(-1-x^2)}$?

Assuming the form in $(*)$, I was able to determine $t\notin\mathbb{C}(x)$, since if $t=\frac{f}{g}$ for some $f,g\in\mathbb{C}[x]$, squaring and rearranging gives
$g^2\cdot (-1-x^2)=f^2\cdot (i-x)^3$, a contradiction by looking at degrees. I get a tower
$$
\mathbb{C}(x)\subsetneq\mathbb{C}(x,t)\subseteq K
$$
so $\mathbb{C}(x,t)=K$. This just brings me back to wanting to show $x\in\mathbb{C}(t)$. But this seems obvious from the get go, so I don't know how to proceed, and I haven't used anything about transcendence degrees.

Comment: Show that $\Bbb{C}(t^2)=\Bbb{C}(x)$

Comment: @reuns Since $t^2=(-1-x^2)/(i-x)^3$, $t^2\in\mathbb{C}(x)$, but showing $x\in\mathbb{C}(t^2)$ is an even stronger thing than showing $x\in\mathbb{C}(t)$ which is my issue?

Comment: Very likely they meant to write $t=(i-x)^{-1}\sqrt{-1-x^2}$, but weren't sure if to write a denominator or a factor with exponent $-1$ and the text ended up with both. This way we have $t^2=\frac{i+x}{i-x}$, where the linear fractional transformation has inverse (also a linear fractional transformation). So, $x$ is that rational function of $t$ (of $t^2$). This gives $x\in \mathbb{C}(t)$ and also $\sqrt{-1-x^2}=t(i-x)\in\mathbb{C}(t)$.

Comment: @user85667 Thanks! Much more sensible correction to the typo and the exercise became clear.

Comment: Note that $t= i\sqrt{x^2+1}/(x-i)^2$ doesn't work,

$\Bbb{C}(t^2)=\Bbb{C}( (x+i)/(x-i)^3)$ so $[\Bbb{C}(x):\Bbb{C}(t^2)]=3$ and 
$[\Bbb{C}(x,t):\Bbb{C}(t^2)]=6$ whence $[\Bbb{C}(x,t):\Bbb{C}(t)]=3$